# QWebException: "coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found" while evaluating

Tags: python, sql, odoo, openerp-7

I have a problem in my code  :

```
def exam_day_date (self,day_id_date):
        id_date= []
        self._cr.execute(
            """select week_day,exam_date ,s.name,t.sasa_zozo,y.teacher_ids from fci_exam_time_table_line, fci_subject s ,rel_sa t,lgna_teacher y  where exam_id = %d group by week_day,exam_date ,s.name,t.sasa_zozo,y.teacher_ids order by exam_date  """ % (
            day_id_date))
        res = self._cr.dictfetchall()
        self._cr.execute(
            """select week_day,exam_date ,s.name,t.sasa_zozo,y.teacher_ids from fci_exam_time_table_line, fci_subject s ,rel_sa t,lgna_teacher y  where exam_id = %d group by week_day,exam_date ,s.name,t.sasa_zozo,y.teacher_ids order by exam_date   """ % (
            day_id_date))
        time_data = self._cr.dictfetchall()
        for time_detail in time_data:
            for data in res:
               time_detail[data['week_day']] = '('+data['week_day']+')\n'+data['exam_date']+'\n('+data['name']+')'+data['sasa_zozo']+data['teacher_ids']
            id_date.append(time_detail)
        print (id_date)
        return id_date
```

where week_day ,name are chars and exam_date is date but sasa_zozo and teacher_ids are intgers

when i try to print a report it gives me error

Answer (score 1):

convert the integers to string and pass it report template for printing

```
def exam_day_date (self,day_id_date):
        id_date= []
        self._cr.execute(
            """select week_day,exam_date ,s.name,t.sasa_zozo,y.teacher_ids from fci_exam_time_table_line, fci_subject s ,rel_sa t,lgna_teacher y  where exam_id = %d group by week_day,exam_date ,s.name,t.sasa_zozo,y.teacher_ids order by exam_date  """ % (
            day_id_date))
        res = self._cr.dictfetchall()
        self._cr.execute(
            """select week_day,exam_date ,s.name,t.sasa_zozo,y.teacher_ids from fci_exam_time_table_line, fci_subject s ,rel_sa t,lgna_teacher y  where exam_id = %d group by week_day,exam_date ,s.name,t.sasa_zozo,y.teacher_ids order by exam_date   """ % (
            day_id_date))
        time_data = self._cr.dictfetchall()
        for time_detail in time_data:
            for data in res:
               time_detail[data['week_day']] = '('+data['week_day']+')\n'+data['exam_date']+'\n('+data['name']+')'+str(data['sasa_zozo'])+str(data['teacher_ids'])
            id_date.append(time_detail)
        print (id_date)
        return id_date
```

you were trying to append an integer to a string, that was the reason for the error

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475077/how-to-retrive-values-in-many2one-field-as-selection-field